# prove there are $n$ homomorphisms from $C_n \to C_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

prove there are $n$ homomorphisms from $C_n \to C_n$

define $\phi_a : C_n \to C_n$ by $\phi_a(x) = x^a$, I have proved that $phi_a$ is ahomomorphism and I want to show that there are n homomorphisms from $C_n \to C_n$ - how can i proceed?

Comment: Say $g$ generates $C_n$. A morphism $\varphi:C_n\to C_n$ is entirely determined by where you send $g$. You have at least $n$ choices for $g$, and you must show each of these is a different morphism. You can do this by showing, for example, that each $\varphi_a$ (as in your notation, I assume also $x=g$ in your notation) has a unique order, related to the value of $a$. In fact, for any abelian group $G$, ${\rm Hom}_\Bbb Z(C_n,G)\simeq G[n]=\{x\in G:nx=0\}$. In particular, since $C_n[n]=n$, you get ${\rm Hom}_\Bbb Z(C_n,C_n)=C_n$.